# How can I limit the total number of database entries read by RepositoryItemReader of my Spring Batch Multithreaded Step process?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-batch

My Multithreaded Spring Batch Step is behaving almost erratically. I haven't been able to discern any kind of pattern in the ways it's failing. Sometimes it reads and writes too many records from the database and sometimes it doesn't read enough.

I'm using a RepositoryItemReader to execute a custom native query. I've defined a countQuery for it and I've used the reader's `setMaxItemCount(totalLimit)` method, but it seems to consider that more of a suggestion rather than an actual hard maximum. Because with a thread count of 4, and just 1 intentionally bad record that causes 1 skip in the processor logic, I've seen...

```
limit | pageSize | chunkSize || actual writes
100   | 10       | 5         || 110 unique writes
800   | 100      | 25        || 804 unique writes, and 37 duplicate writes (WHY?)
800   | 100      | 25        || 663 unique writes, and 165 duplicate writes (WHYYYY???)
```

My project is using Spring Boot 2.1.11.RELEASE and it looks like the version of spring-batch-infrastructure that's pulling in is 4.1.3.RELEASE. Does anyone have any idea why Spring Batch is performing either too many or duplicate writes when just 1 skip occurs on one of the pages?

Maybe it has something to do with the way I've configured my in-memory JobRepository...

Here's my repository class:

```java
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {
    String FROM_MY_ENTITY_TABLE_LEFT_JOINED_WITH_ANOTHER_TABLE = "from {h-schema}my_entity e" +
        "left join {h-schema}another_table a" +
        "on e.fk = a.pk ";

    @Query(
        value = "select e.id, e.name, a.additional_info" +
           FROM_MY_ENTITY_TABLE_LEFT_JOINED_WITH_ANOTHER_TABLE +
           "where e.status <> :status and e.add_date < :date",
        countjQuery = "select count(*) " +
           FROM_MY_ENTITY_TABLE_LEFT_JOINED_WITH_ANOTHER_TABLE +
           "where e.status <> :status and e.add_date < :date",
        nativeQuery = true)
    Page<MyProjection> findMyProjectionsWithoutStatusBeforeDate(@Param("status") String status, 
                                                                @Param("date") Date date,
                                                                Pageable page);
}
```

And here's how I've configured my job:

```java
@Configuration
public class ConversionBatchJobConfig {

    @Bean
    public SimpleCompletionPolicy processChunkSize(@Value("${commit.chunk.size:5}") Integer chunkSize) {
        return new SimpleCompletionPolicy(chunkSize);
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemStreamReader<MyProjection> dbReader(
            MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository,
            @Value("#{jobParameters[startTime]}") Date startTime,
            @Value("#{jobParameters[pageSize]}") Integer pageSize,
            @Value("#{jobParameters[limit]}") Integer limit) {
        RepositoryItemReader<MyProjection> myProjectionRepositoryReader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
        myProjectionRepositoryReader.setRepository(myEntityRepository);
        myProjectionRepositoryReader.setMethodName("findMyProjectionsWithoutStatusBeforeDate");
        myProjectionRepositoryReader.setArguments(new ArrayList<Object>() {{
            add("REMOVED");
            add(startTime);
        }});
        myProjectionRepositoryReader.setSort(new HashMap<String, Sort.Direction>() {{
            put("e.id", Sort.Direction.ASC);
        }});
        myProjectionRepositoryReader.setPageSize(pageSize);
        myProjectionRepositoryReader.setMaxItemCount(limit);
        myProjectionRepositoryReader.setSaveState(false);
        return myProjectionRepositoryReader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemProcessor<MyProjection, JsonMessage> dataConverter(AdditionalDbDataRetrievalService dataRetrievalService) {
        return new MyProjectionToJsonMessageConverter(dataRetrievalService); // <== simple ItemProcessor implementation
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<JsonMessage> jsonPublisher(GcpPubsubPublisherService publisherService) {
        return new JsonMessageWriter(publisherService); // <== simple ItemWriter implementation
    }

    @Bean
    public Step conversionProcess(SimpleCompletionPolicy processChunkSize,
                                  ItemStreamReader<MyProjection> dbReader,
                                  ItemProcessor<MyProjection, JsonMessage> dataConverter,
                                  ItemWriter<JsonMessage> jsonPublisher,
                                  StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                                  TaskExecutor conversionThreadPool,
                                  @Value("${conversion.failure.limit:20}") int maximumFailures) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("conversionProcess")
                .<MyProjection, JsonMessage>chunk(processChunkSize)
                .reader(dbReader)
                .processor(dataConverter)
                .writer(jsonPublisher)
                .faultTolerant()
                .skipPolicy(new MyCustomConversionSkipPolicy(maximumFailures))
                            //  ^ for now this returns true for everything until 20 failures
                    .listener(new MyConversionSkipListener(processStatus))
                              //  ^ for now this just logs the error
                .taskExecutor(conversionThreadPool)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job conversionJob(Step conversionProcess,
                             JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("conversionJob")
                .start(conversionProcess)
                .build();
    }
}
```

And here's how I've configured my in-memory Job Repository:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class InMemoryBatchManagementConfig {

    @Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager resourcelessTransactionManager() {
        ResourcelessTransactionManager resourcelessTransactionManager = new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
        return resourcelessTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactory(ResourcelessTransactionManager resourcelessTransactionManager)
            throws Exception {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(resourcelessTransactionManager);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory) throws Exception {
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        launcher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return launcher;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExplorer jobExplorer(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory) {
        return new SimpleJobExplorer(factory.getJobInstanceDao(), factory.getJobExecutionDao(),
                factory.getStepExecutionDao(), factory.getExecutionContextDao());
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactory,
                                           ResourcelessTransactionManager resourceslessTransactionManager,
                                           SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher,
                                           JobExplorer jobExplorer) {
        return new BatchConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public JobRepository getJobRepository() throws Exception {
                return mapJobRepositoryFactory.getObject();
            }

            @Override
            public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws Exception {
                return resourceslessTransactionManager;
            }

            @Override
            public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws Exception {
                return jobLauncher;
            }

            @Override
            public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() throws Exception {
                return jobExplorer;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---

### **EDIT**

Was able to get Spring Batch working with an H2 database instead of a Map repository, but I'm still seeing the same issue. Here's how I configured batch to use H2:

I imported the H2 driver:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.200</version>
</dependency>
```

I configured my primary DB config to point to my JPA entities:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.company.project.jpa.repository", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.company.project.jpa.entity")
public class DbConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("oracle.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
                                                                       EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.company.project.jpa").build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }
}
```

And then I configured my in-memory Batch management like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class InMemoryBatchManagementConfig {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public EmbeddedDatabase h2DataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-h2.sql")
                .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean h2EntityManagerFactory(EmbeddedDatabase h2DataSource,
                                                                         EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(h2DataSource).packages("org.springframework.batch.core").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager h2TransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("h2EntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean h2EntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(h2EntityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(EmbeddedDatabase h2DataSource,
                                       @Qualifier("h2TransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager h2TransactionManager) throws Exception {
        final JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDatabaseType(DatabaseType.H2.getProductName());
        factory.setDataSource(h2DataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(h2TransactionManager);
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean(EmbeddedDatabase h2DataSource,
                                                             @Qualifier("h2TransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager h2TransactionManager) {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new  JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(h2DataSource);
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(h2TransactionManager);
        return jobRepositoryFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(JobRepository jobRepository,
                                           SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher,
                                           @Qualifier("h2TransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager h2TransactionManager,
                                           JobExplorer jobExplorer) {
        return new BatchConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public JobRepository getJobRepository() {
                return jobRepository;
            }

            @Override
            public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
                return h2TransactionManager;
            }

            @Override
            public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() {
                return jobLauncher;
            }

            @Override
            public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() {
                return jobExplorer;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a JDBC based job repository with an in-memory database (like h2, hsqldb, etc) and `DataSourceTransactionManager` instead of the `MapBasedJobRepository` + `ResourcelessTransactionManager` ? There is a similar open issue here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1085, but I want to make sure it is not related to the usage of a Map-based job repository in a multi-threaded context.

Comment: Oh sure, I can give that a shot. I'm having trouble finding a good example of setting up an H2 database along side a real SQL database in a Spring Boot App, but I'm still googling. I wonder if Spring Batch docs have any examples of that, do you know?

Comment: nothing specific to Spring Batch for that. You configure two datasources in your application context and tell Spring Batch which one to use for the job repository. A bare bones project generated from start.spring.io with spring batch + h2 should give you that setup automatically, here is a link to generate such project: https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.3.0.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=1.8&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=batch,h2,jdbc.

Comment: I was able to get spring batch working with an H2 database, but I'm still seeing the same issue. I'll edit my question to show my H2 configuration.

Comment: It seems like this is an issue with the coordination of the multithreaded step, or whatever is driving it. Because I've used two different readers, `JpaPagingItemReader` and `RepositoryItemReader`, and neither seems to honor the maxItemCount. In fact both seem to process the same record multiple times. There were only 5000 entries matching my query, and it wrote 9000 before I killed the process. No skips/errors in that run... I'm wondering if I'm not supposed to use ItemStreamReaders for a multithreaded step? Should I be using a SynchronizedItemReader?

Comment: If you believe this is the same as https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1085, please add a comment on that issue. If you have a minimal example that reliably reproduces the issue, it would be appreciated to attach it.